# How to know which Tile size now is active

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm developing Windows Phone 8 application with Iconic live tile support. On the Iconic live tile I need to show count of items in the Application but small Icon tile support only max 99 digits.

So I want to know could I some how determin which tile size now is active and show for small Icon tile count 0 (empty) if items count > 99 and for medium show real items count.

And if not what I can do with it.

Thanks.

Comment: 99 is the limit no matter the size of the tile

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. There is no information about active tile size. You can build the tile by self (generate image in your app) and you can show anything on the tile in this case.